# sitemap generator in rails with subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sitemap

I have a site with 1000s of user.
and my site looks like http://username.site.com .

I verified that sitemap can have multiple domain names if they are verified.
[Sitemap for a site with a large number of dynamic subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880621/sitemap-for-a-site-with-a-large-number-of-dynamic-subdomains)

I am using sitemap_generator plugin to generate sitemap. ( seems the most popular)

https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator

I am forming the url in sitemap.rb as follows

```
 User.find_each do |user|
add '/' , :lastmod => user.updated_at ,:host=>"http://"+user.user_name+".site.com" ,:priority => 0.8
end
```

The username also contains "_" .. underscore

so some url are formed as http://user_name_with_underscore.site.com

The sitemap generator throws error

> the scheme http does not accept registry part:
>   user_name_with_underscore (or bad hostname?)

Now how do I get past this problem ??

And  is '_' a bad idea in subdomains ?

Comment: Generally "-" is preferred over "_" in urls.

Comment: oh k.. will keep that in mind for new data..

Comment: is it a typo that you forgot a dot just before the "site.com"?